# (Java) how to make a system where you have ints trees, wood and cash, and you have trees/s , wood/s and cash/s

Tags: java, android, math

This is probably a very stupid question, but I am stuck with this problem for already several days

So you have an int trees, and int wood and cash. Trees will be converted into wood and wood will be converted into cash.

You also have an int treespersecond, int woodpersecond and cashpersecond.

Each second treespersecond will be added to trees. Each second woodpersecond will be added to wood and subtracted from trees. (You need trees for making wood). And each second cashpersecond will be added to cash en subtracted from wood.(wood will result into cash).

Each .persecond value has their own values. Also trees, wood cash had an maximum value and they can't be lower then 0.

So how to make a system which does all of this every second.

I know who to make a run method which runs every second.

So you have to do something like this:

```
Trees += treespersecond
Trees -= woodpersecond 
Wood += woodpersecond
Wood -= cashpersecond 
Cash += cashpersecond
```

But now the values can be higher then their maximum value and lower then zero. How to fixed this problem: how to still keep the values between their limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use `if-statement`?

```
if (Trees < MAX_TREES) {
    Trees += treespersecond;
}
if (Wood < MAX_WOOD && Trees > 0) {
    Trees -= woodpersecond;
    Wood += woodpersecond;
}
if (Cash < MAX_CASH && Wood > 0) {
    Wood -= cashpersecond;
    Cash += cashpersecond;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To respectively handle underflows and overflows, you can compare your value to Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE.

I think you should not register ressources under 0 in your case for trees, cashs, etc.

Java handles automatically overflows by giving to the variable the max value :

```
int counter = 999999999999999;

if (counter > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {

counter = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

}
```

If you are quite sure to reach the limit, you can use **BigInteger** instead.

For ressources maximum values, the pattern is the same : a simple if statement.

```
int trees = 0;
int treesPerSecond = 10;
int maxTrees = 100;

trees += treesPerSecond;

if (trees > maxTrees) {

trees = maxTrees;

}

else if (trees < 0) {

trees = 0;

}
```